# Ordenar lista doble circular en lenguaje c

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de hacer una función que me ordene una lista de este tipo, hasta el momento hice una que ordena una lista doble pero no se como cambiarla para que haga lo que deseo

Este es el código de mi función:

```
void ordena_lista(Nodo *nodo){

    Nodo *actual, *siguiente;
    int n;

    actual = nodo;
    while(actual->sig != NULL) {
      siguiente = actual->sig;
      while(siguiente != NULL) {
        if(actual->num < siguiente->num) {
          n = siguiente->num;
          siguiente->num = actual->num;
          actual->num = n;
        }
        siguiente = siguiente->sig;
      }
      actual = actual->sig;
      siguiente = actual->sig;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a suponer que el parámetro **nodo** que le pasas a la función es el primero de la lista.

Entonces el código yo lo resolvería de la siguiente manera:

```
void ordena_lista(Nodo *nodo)
{
    int n;
    Nodo *actual, *siguiente;

    if(nodo != NULL)
    {
        actual = nodo;
        do
        {
            siguiente = actual->sig;
            while(siguiente != nodo)
            {
                if(actual->num > siguiente->num)
                {
                    n = siguiente->num;
                    siguiente->num = actual->num;
                    actual->num = n;
                }
                siguiente = siguiente->sig;
            }
            actual = actual->sig;
            siguiente = actual->sig;
        }
        while(siguiente != nodo);
    }
}
```